# Google Workspaces Users Drives API to watch activity with files

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I know how to use Google Drive API to watch user's activity with files. For that I create 'changes' objects with that url: drive/v3/changes/watch.
But how to deal with Google Workspaces API? As an admin, I want to watch for all users' drives activities (adding new files, changing them). I'm as an admin, can get a list of users. And how I can watch all drives of all users in the Workspace?

Comment: Do you have a billing account or a private domain?

Comment: Jose, I have a billing account.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Google Workspace Admin SDK > [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)

Specifically `Method: activities.list` on this API which allows you to retrieve all user activities given certain parameters, i.e.

**Try API**

[https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list?apix_params={"userKey":"all"](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22:%22all%22), "applicationName":"drive", "eventName":"edit", "startTime":"2021-02-22T10:26:35.000Z"}

Or

**Request**

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?eventName=edit&startTime=2021-02-22T10:26:35.000Z
```

The parameter **eventName** can be **edit, add_to_folder, create, delete, ...** among several events.

All Drive Audit Activity Events can be consulted [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive)